# Transform Response From Azure Table Storage With Node

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, lodash, hapi.js

I am creating a REST API with Node which reads from Azure Table Storage.

The output is similar to the following:

```
[  
   {  
      "PartitionKey":{  
         "$":"Edm.String",
         "_":"sdsdsdsd"
      },
      "RowKey":{  
         "$":"Edm.String",
         "_":"sdsdsdsdsd"
      },
      "Timestamp":{  
         "$":"Edm.DateTime",
         "_":"2015-08-20T01:56:37.499Z"
      },
      "Destination":{  
         "_":"sdsdsdsdsd"
      },
      "QueryParameters":{  
         "_":"sdsddsadsadsd"
      },
      "Referrer":{  
         "_":"sddsadsadss"
      },
      "RequestTime":{  
         "$":"Edm.DateTime",
         "_":"sdsddsdsd"
      },
      "SiteUrl":{  
         "_":"sdsdsdsdd"
      },
      ".metadata":{  
         "etag":"W/"datetime'2015-08-20T01:56:37.4999599Z'""
      }
   }
]
```

I am using lodash as I want to transform the response so it has the following:

- All properties are lowercase. E.g. PartitionKey becomes partitionkey
- Remove all properties which have the key '$'
- If their is only a single property in the object and its key is '_', assign the value to the parent and remove the need for the object.

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you assigned your json object to the `raw` object, 
here is one way to do it on lodash.

First normalising the keys before to handle the values:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const lowKey = _.mapKeys(raw, (v,k) => k.toLowerCase())[0]
const norm = _.mapValues(lowKey, (v)=> {
    delete v.$
    if(Object.keys(v).length ===1 && v._) return v._;
    else return v;
});
console.log(norm)
```